# Testing NotFoundPage with jest & Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I just joined a front team and I am asked to do some tests of the application, 
I need to check that my Not Found page appears only if the user does not enter a correct url.

**I know there is MemoryRouter if our application routing use react router but my team does not use it:**

```
<MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/random"]}>
    <Routes />
</MemoryRouter>
```

**this is the component that manages the routing:**

```js
const routes = {
  path: "",
  children: [
    {
      path: "/",
      load: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'home' */ "./home")
    },
    {
      path: "/login",
      load: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'login' */ "./login")
    },
    {
      path: "/delivery",
      load: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'delivery' */ "./delivery")
    },
    {
      path: "/offers",
      load: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'delivery' */ "./offers")
    },
    // Wildcard routes, e.g. { path: '(.*)', ... } (must go last)
    {
      path: "(.*)",
      load: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'not-found' */ "./not-found")
    }
  ],
  async action({ next }) {
    const route = await next();
    return route;
  }
};

**export default routes:**
```

**So I still tried with MemoryRouter but it does not work:**

```js
import React from "react";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import NotFoundPage from "../routes/not-found/NotFound";
import Routes from "../routes/index";

describe("testing NotFoundPage", () => {
  it("should go to 404 page", () => {
    const component = mount(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/random"]}>
        <Routes />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
    expect(component.find(NotFoundPage)).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: this is not an error, it is that MemoryRouter is used if the application uses react router and in my case I do not know how to test page 404

Comment: What's the output of the unit testing then ? Since you said it does not work, I assume there is some kind of error message.

Comment: link to the output here(https://photos.app.goo.gl/WV8dCRfytVx6PHC37)

Comment: Well the error message is quite explicit. You need to configure enzyme with [your adapter](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme). `Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });`

Comment: Yes sorry, I have make this now ! But I have this (https://photos.app.goo.gl/DE9WS9qMYESQ1YFn7)

Comment: well, again the error message explicitly says that you export not an react component (but object). You need to check [how to configure routes properly](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config).